# How to abort a bash script in n seconds

Tags: bash

I want to make my script wait for n seconds, during which user can abort the script. My code till now looks like this

```
echo "Start Date provided :" $STARTDATE
echo "End date provided :" $ENDDATE
echo ""
echo "Please check the dates provided and in case of error press CTRL+C"
seq 1 15 |while read i; do echo -ne "\rWaiting for $i seconds"; sleep 1; done
echo ""
echo "Executing query on the remote side, please wait..."
```

When the user presses ctrl+c though what happens is that the while loop ends and continues executing the rest of the script.

How can I make it abort the entire script? Thanks in advance for any advise

Comment: One way would be to register a signal handler for SIGINT. I don't know if that's overly complicated though.

Comment: Why the while loop? Just `sleep` for x seconds. Once you hit CTRL+C, the script will terminate.

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #68](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068), and a very, very commonly asked question on this site (apparently by virtue of folks not checking the FAQ).

Comment: You should accept correct answer with green tick mark and remember you can vote-up more good answers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use trap

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo -e "\nBye"; exit 1' INT

echo "Please check the dates provided and in case of error press CTRL+C"
seq 1 15 |while read i; do echo -ne "\rWaiting for $i seconds"; sleep 1; done
echo "Executing query on the remote side, please wait..."
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried that, quick and easy solution

Answer (score 0):

To catch `CTRL+C` you can use `trap`. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'got_one' 2

got_one() {
 echo "I got one"
 exit 69
}

echo -e "PID: $$, PPID: $PPID" 
sleep 100
```

So your script can look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "interrupt" SIGINT

interrupt() {
  echo -e "\nExecution canceled."
  exit 69
}

countdown() {
  duration=$1 # in seconds
  seq $duration -1 0|while read i; do echo -ne "\rWaiting for $i seconds"; sleep 1; done
}

STARTDATE="foo"
ENDDATE="bar"

cat <<END
Start Date provided: $STARTDATE
  End date provided: $ENDDATE

Please check the dates provided and in case of error press CTRL+C
END

countdown 15

echo -e "\nExecuting query on the remote side, please wait..."
```

Comment: as for functions parameters you can use `$1` without assigning it to another variable however I find it a good habit to name them which makes it clear for future reading

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler program that reproduces your problem:

```
true | sleep 10  # Hit Ctrl-C here
echo "why does this execute?"
```

The problem is that `bash` determines whether or not to continue the script based on whether the SIGINT was handled. It determines whether the SIGINT was handled based on whether or not the process it's currently running is killed by this signal.

Since `seq` prints its numbers and exits immediately and successfully, it's not killed by SIGINT. `bash` therefore incorrectly assumes the signal was handled, and it keeps going.

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Add a SIGINT handler that exits your script regardless of whether the signal appears to be handled.
2. Don't use seq or anything else that immediately exits.

For the first approach, see [user3620917's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23575040/1899640).

The second approach,

```
for i in {15..1}
do 
  printf '\rYou have %d seconds to hit Ctrl-C' "$i"
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really liked your insights apart from just the solution!